# Finding specific words in a sentence using regex

Tags: python, regex

I want to match specific words in a sentence using Regex (python)for example

`<Loc>UK</Loc> to ban all <fuelV>petrol and diesel</fuelV> in <Date>2040</Date>`

The result will be Group1: (Uk) Group2: (ban fuelV Date) Group3:(2024). I tried this

```
<Loc>(.*)?</Loc>(?:.*(ban).*)<Date>(.*)?</Date>
```

But the result was UK , ban, 2024

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`<Loc>(.*)?</Loc>.*(ban).*<(.*)>.*</.*>.*<(Date)>(.*)?</Date>` can be used to match UK, ban, fuelV, Date, 2040 (each in their own capturing group.)